# EF Core - Navigational Properties - populating ALL related types

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I have an EF Core question, based on the simplified example below:

```
public class House {
    public int NumberOfBedrooms { get; set; }

    public virtual FrontDoor FrontDoor { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class FrontDoor {
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual House House { get; set; }
}
```

Get a list of houses and include the FrontDoor property of the House object

```
var houses = _dbContext.Houses
              .Include(x => x.FrontDoor)
              .ToList();
```

Get the House that has FrontDoor HouseNumber 10

```
var house10 = houses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FrontDoor.HouseNumber == 10);
```

Then if I want to get the NumberOfBedrooms in `house10` I can write the code in 2 different ways:

1)

```
var numberOfBedrooms = house10.NumberOfBedrooms;
```

This works without any errors, however if I re-write the way I get the NumberOfBedrooms I can cause a null reference exception.

2)

```
var numberOfBedrooms = house10.FrontDoor.House.NumberOfBedrooms;
```

To stop this NRE I have to change the initial `houses` query to:

```
var houses = _dbContext.Houses
              .Include(x => x.FrontDoor)
              .Include(x => x.FrontDoor.House)
              .ToList();
```

1) Is this the correct way to include the `House` property twice by using the 2 `.Include()` methods?

2) Is there away to stop access to the `House` navigation property on the FrontDoor object - I believe its required for the migrations to create the correct SQL table relationships?

Comment: I don't really understand, solution1 works, solution 2 doesn't work. What's the issue?